# Ansible fails to connect on second task

Tags: ansible

Running a playbook with the common role, Ansible completes the first task successfully, but fails on subsequent ones.

```
 $ ansible-playbook new_deployment.yml -i hosts -l vm01 --check --ask-become-pass -vvv
```

Contents of new_deployment.yml

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: yes
  no_log: true # don't log sensitive information. This can also apply to individual tasks
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "hostname"
      prompt: "FQDN of host"
      private: no
    - name: "domain_admin_username"
      prompt: "Domain Admin username for realmd"
      private: no
    - name: "domain_admin_password"
      prompt: "Password for Domain Admin for realmd"
      private: yes
  roles:
    - 'common'
```

Contents of roles/common/tasks/main.yml (only first two tasks)

```yaml
---
  - name: Set Hostname
    ansible.builtin.hostname:
      name: "{{ hostname }}"
      # use: "redhat"

  - name: Set Timezone to UTC
    ansible.builtin.command:
      cmd: "timedatectl set-timezone UTC"
```

Ansible sets the hostname but fails on the timezone task.

```
    changed: [vm01] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_domain": "localdomain",
        "ansible_fqdn": "localhost.localdomain",
        "ansible_hostname": "blah",
        "ansible_nodename": "blah"
    },
    "changed": true,
    "diff": {
        "after": "hostname = blah\n",
        "before": "hostname = localhost\n"
    },
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "name": "blah",
            "use": null
        }
    },
    "name": "blah"
}

    fatal: [vm01]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer",
    "unreachable": true
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
apex01                     : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I don't understand the issue because I am able to ssh to the vm no problem, and it connects on the first task anyways.

**Edit**:
I think there is a firewall which is blocking SSH connections on repeated connections. I'll have to verify with our network admin.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration item `MaxStartups` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` might cause this.

[Difference between maxstartups and maxsessions in sshd_config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114690/difference-between-maxstartups-and-maxsessions-in-sshd-config)